# How can I define multiple names for a parameter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

In Chrome DevTools' Console, you can see that some function parameters have multiple different names.

This is an intuitive and simple signifier that a parameter accepts multiple different types of arguments.

How can I define multiple names for parameters in my own functions?

[image: Multiple parameter names in a function]

---

The closest thing I found to this was defining multiple different parameters. However, this is more confusing than anything, as it gets ugly when you attempt to access any parameter other than the first:

[image: Multiple parameters]

---

*Note: In some other languages, you can define multiple names for parameters using [function overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading).*